# Ошибка в программе бота телеграмм для python

Tags: python, telebot

Использую модуль telebot. решил написать простенькое:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('776550937:AAELEr0c3H6dM-9QnlDD-0Q0Fcd65pPyAiM')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

bot.polling()
```

(На сайте было)
Запускаю через cmd и выдаёт сначала одну ошибку. Её исправил но после появилась другая:

```
2019-06-18 23:35:23,717 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 401 Unauthorized. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"Unauthorized"}\']',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 276, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 246, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 56, in _make_request
    return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 75, in _check_result
    raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 401 Unauthorized. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"Unauthorized"}']
"
2019-06-18 23:35:23,730 (__init__.py:417 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 401 Unauthorized. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"Unauthorized"}']"
```

Comment: Вы зарегистрировали своего бота через Bot Father-а в телеграмме? Это точно ваш токен?

Comment: @Jazzis, да это мой токен. И создавал я с помощью bot father

Comment: Удалите токен, изменив код так: `bot = telebot.TeleBot(mytoken)`

Answer (score 0):

> Вы зарегистрировали своего бота через Bot Father-а в телеграмме? Это точно ваш токен? – Jazzis

Всё таки это был старый токен от старого бота. Проблема решилась. Спасибо